# Passing custom class to connect (signals and slot)

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

i'm trying to create a new dialog with some text input fields. These text areas, on a button click (as a confirmation), have to be inserted into a custom class vector (through existing methods).

My doubt is, how can i fit the connect function to pass the custom class as a reference? I'm very newbie on this, please forgive my dumbness.
This is (part of) my code.

```
#include "aggiungi.h"
#include "ui_aggiungi.h"


aggiungi::aggiungi(clienti& c, QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::aggiungi)
{

ui->setupUi(this);

connect(ui->inserisci,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(pulsanteInserisci(c)));

}

aggiungi::~aggiungi()
{
  delete ui;
}

void aggiungi::pulsanteInserisci(clienti& c) {

string nome = ui->textNome->toPlainText().toStdString();
unsigned int cc = ui->textCod->toPlainText().toUInt();
string piva = ui->textPIva->toPlainText().toStdString();

cliente* nc = new cliente(nome,cc,piva);
c.aggiungi(*nc);

}
```

All i want to is to be able to pass the "clienti" object in order to execute the commands when the button is clicked. This solution is (obviously) not working but how can i correct it? What's your suggestion?

I'll also paste the error i'm getting out of the application output:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot aggiungi::pulsanteInserisci(c) 
in..\Progetto2016\git\database\aggiungi.cpp:9
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'inserisci')
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'aggiungi')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the old signal/slot syntax. Use [the new syntax introduced in Qt5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and the issue here should become clear.

Comment: @MrEricSir due to some project restrictions I have to use Qt creator 4 and old version compiler minGW 4.8.3, i don't know if the new syntax is supported already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass values to `SIGNAL()` or `SLOT()` macros. You must pass the *signature*. Furthermore, the signal and slot must be compatible. In other words, the signatures must match. See the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) for more details.

Having said that, there is no way you can connect a button's `clicked()` signal to a slot that requires any argument. A simple solution is to store `clienti` as a member variable and use the member variable in `pulsanteInserisci()`.

Answer (score 0):

connect should be:

connect(ui->inserisci,SIGNAL(clicked(clienti&)),this,SLOT(pulsanteInserisci(clienti&)));

or

connect(ui->inserisci,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(pulsanteInserisci()));

Comment: But using this way, how can i set what to pass to the function pulsanteInserisci() on click?

Comment: The arguments must be compatible when you establish a connection between a signal and a slot. The signal can have more arguments than the slot has, but not the other way around.

Comment: so it should be: connect(ui->inserisci,SIGNAL(clicked(clienti&)),this,SLOT(pulsanteInserisci(clienti&)));  or: connect(ui->inserisci,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(pulsanteInserisci()));